# Configure Conky to display arbitrary measurements as a number / percent / bar / graph / guage

Tags: desktop-customization, conky, system-monitoring

Does Conky allow me to display an arbitrary measurement as a bar, gauge, graph, etc? Or only the ones that it provides explicit objects for, eg. CPU usage can be displayed as any of:

- `${cpuN}` : A numeric percentage
- `${cpubar N ...}` : A horizontal bar
- `${cpuguage N ...}` : A circular gauge
- `${cpugraph N ...}` : A slowly side-scrolling graph of historical values

But for other values, such as CPU temperature, there is only the option of displaying as text by using the provided built-in objects, or spawning an external processes, such as:

- `${hwmon 5 temp 6}` : A built-in object to return a number in degrees C.
- `${exec sensors coretemp-isa-0000 | grep 'Package id 0' | awk '{print $4}'}` : An external command to do the same (which suffers a performance penalty for spawning processes on every poll)

Can I convert the output of these last two examples into a graphical representation, eg. displaying CPU temperature as a circular gauge? I'm especially interested in answers which are general-purpose enough to apply to any of the conky built-in objects or results of 'exec', not just specific to CPU temperature.

An acceptable answer might include a modern replacement for Conky, that learns from the once-trailblazing and venerable Conky's now well-understood design shortfalls? (eg. [one](https://superuser.com/questions/1748537/configure-conky-to-display-arbitrary-measurements-as-a-number-percent-bar), [two](https://superuser.com/questions/1748545/can-conky-display-detailed-information-without-being-specifically-configured-to))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to its `man` file, Conky provides `execbar`, `execgauge`, and `execgraph` for executing a shell command and displaying its results. Additionally, Conky provides `execibar`, `execigauge`, and `execgraph` for doing the same at a specific interval.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it. This would solve the problem as I posed it. Although the question says I'd rather avoid the performance penalty of spawning a new process each time Conky updates, this is probably the only way to do it.